# Solve simultaneous quadratic equations $ x^2-2xy=21$ and $xy+y^2 = 18$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve:

$$ 
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x^2-2xy=21 \\ 
xy+y^2=18 
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

$\rightarrow$ $\left\{\begin{array}{l}x(x-2y)=21 \cdot \cdot \cdot(1) \\ y(x+y) = 18  \cdot \cdot \cdot(2)\end{array} \right. $

From $(2)$:

$x=\dfrac{18}{y}-y$

Plug this back into $(1)$:

$(\dfrac{18}{y}-y)(\dfrac{18}{y}-y-2y)=21\cdot \cdot \cdot(I)$

$(\dfrac{18}{y}-y)(\dfrac{18}{y}-3y)=21\cdot \cdot \cdot(II)$

$(\dfrac{18-y^2}{y})(\dfrac{18-3y^2}{y})=21\cdot \cdot \cdot(III)$

$(18-y^2)(18-3y^2)=21y^2\cdot \cdot \cdot(IV)$

$324-54y^2-18y^2+3y^4=21y^2\cdot \cdot \cdot(V)$

$3y^4-93y^2+324=0\cdot \cdot \cdot(VI)$

$y^4-31y^2+108=0\cdot \cdot \cdot(VII)$

$(y^2-27)(y^2-4)=0\cdot \cdot \cdot(VIII)$

Thus $y=\pm3\sqrt{3} , \pm2$

Plug the $y$ values back into $(2)$ to get $x$ values:

For $y=3\sqrt{3} \\ x=\dfrac{18}{3\sqrt{3}}-3\sqrt{3} \\ x=\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{3}}-(3\sqrt{3})\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}} \\ x = \dfrac{6}{\sqrt{3}}-\dfrac{9}{\sqrt{3}} \\ x=\dfrac{-3}{\sqrt{3}}$

Plugging in the other $y$ values, and solve the problem:

$x=\dfrac{-3}{\sqrt{3}} , y = 3\sqrt{3}\\ x=\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{3}}, y =-3\sqrt{3}\\ x=7, y=2 \\ x=-7, -2$

My problem is the answers are slightly different in the book:

$x=-\sqrt{3} , y = 3\sqrt{3}\\ x=\sqrt{3}, y =-3\sqrt{3}\\ x=7, y=2 \\ x=-7, y=-2$

I feel it's a typo in the book, but I can't be sure. Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: $\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{3}}$ is not even "*slightly*" different from $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Most text books exercises will rationalize the denominators in their answers if it's possible. Try doing it with your results!

Comment: Between the 2 given Equations , you can eliminate $xy$ to get $x^2+2 \cdot y^2=57$. Here , you can plug in the Integer Solutions to verify that $7^2+2 \cdot 2^2 = 57$. Likewise , you can verify your other 2 Solutions , hence your Answer is Correct. Now , when you try to verify the textbook Answers , you will immediately figure out that those are Exactly the Same , having the Exact Same Squares !

Comment: If ever you face a situation where your solutions **look** different than the official solutions, try to compare them, like in this case start saying that $\frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{3}$ and move on from there. If you end up with something true (like $1=1$) then your solutions are correct. If you end up with nonsense (like $3=1$) then your solutions are wrong. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but the book applied the simplification $3/\sqrt3=\sqrt3$.

In some cases, an expression with the radical in the denominator might be attractive if it uses smaller numbers than putting the radical in the numerator, like $1/2\sqrt3$ versus $\sqrt3/6$. Here, however, $\sqrt3$ uses the same size numbers as $3/\sqrt3$ and the former, with the radical in the numerator, is usually preferred.

---

The system might have been solved originally by taking a linear combination that eliminates the constant terms:

$(x^2-2xy=21)×6-(xy+y^2=18)×7 \implies \color{blue}{6x^2-19xy-7y^2=0}.$

So if $u=y/x$, then $7u^2+19u-6=0$ and thus $u=y/x\in\{-3,2/7\}$.

Substituting $y=-3x$ into either original equation then gives the roots $x=\pm\sqrt3$, while the second candidate $y=2x/7$ yields $x=\pm7$.